# Online-Offline status realisation in grails

Tags: grails, status

How i can realise the function for checking, is the user online or offline in grails? may I use status field in db and update the value for the field each auth time, or i must use some js stuff? maybe u know some tutors about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets say that online user is user who has requested application at least 10 minutes ago. So you can make special field for user domain, like:

```
User {
  Date lastSeenAt

  static transients = ['online']

  boolean isOnline() {
     return lastSeenAt && lastSeenAt.after(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(10))
  } 
}
```

and periodically update it inside a filter, or controller:

```
User user = //...   
if (!user.lastSeenAt || user.lastSeenAt.before(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(5))
  user.lastSeenAt = new Date()
  user.save()
}
```

Probably you shouldn't update it on every request, only if last update was made some time ago, 5 minutes at this example. This value can be lower, depends on what precision do you like.

Comment: but can I realise it with session, save the last activity only in session, not in db, and last activity from session save in var for showing the time to other usrs?

Comment: but how you will get a session for other user?

Comment: will u method ok with 1 gb ram? i mean speed issues of app, writing and reading to db each 5 min

Comment: and what is TimeUnit? i get an error such this: No such property: TimeUnit for class: blah blah...

Comment: TimeUnit is from Java 1.6. You can use `10 * 60 * 1000` for 10 minutes instead.

Answer (score 0):

the way this is done a lot of places, is by checking last activity from the user. If the time between now, and last activity reaches a certain point, the user is marked offline.

Comment: To better your answer, add some code! It appears that you know what your doing, so share your knowledge :)